# How can I remove an active dictionary from Winedt?

Tags: winedt, dictionaries

Here's an odd one :

I've recently managed, after much toil and pain, to install a French dictionary in Winedt 10 and make it work. The problem now is that I wanted to switch back to English again (for another document), but instead of actually changing the dictionary, I ended up just adding English. So now Winedt accepts all words which are correctly spelled in EITHER French or English, and conversely suggests both French and English words for the misspelled words which do not correspond to a word in any language. Both dictionaries are loaded. It seems like it should be easy to remove one of them in the Dictionary Manager in Winedt by using the "unload" function, but although it tells me that the French dictionary is unloaded, the dictionary is still active. I've also unticked the "load on start" and "save on exit" options, but to no avail. The French dictionary is hellbent on staying active.

Does anybody have a suggestion?

Comment: You just have to declare a submode for your documents, which can be either, say, FR or UK (if you write in english) or US (if you write in american), and make the submode load the corresponding dictionary. via the dictionary manager.

Comment: Yes, I have read something along these lines. According to a suggestion, I am to change the mode filter under the entry of the respective dictionary. This is the French dictionary, where I have added "FR" to the Mode filter :

DICTIONARY="French "
 FILE="%B\Dict\French\fr.dic"
  ENABLED=1
  MODE_FILTER="FR"
  LOAD_ON_START=1
  SAVE_ON_EXIT=1
  ADD_NEW_WORDS=0
  USE_FOR_COMPLETION=1
  ALLOW_COMPOUNDED_WORDS=1

Now I enter the Document Settings accessed by double-clicking on "Tex" is the lower pane of Winedt, and change Document mode to : TeX:FR. However, this does not work...

Comment: @Bernard, do you have any suggestion with respect to this submode? I've tried to follow your suggestion (see previous comment), but I still don't manage to remove the French dictionary or let it be active just for certain documents marked with a specific "mode".

Comment: Did you see what's in your `Dictionaries.ini` file? Here is what I have for the common English dictionary: `DICTIONARY="English (common)"
  FILE="%B\Dict\English\eng_com.dic"
  ENABLED=1
  MODE_FILTER="*;EN;UK;US|FR"
  LOAD_ON_START=0
  SAVE_ON_EXIT=1
  ADD_NEW_WORDS=0
  USE_FOR_COMPLETION=1
  ALLOW_COMPOUNDED_WORDS=1 `  It's similar for all other english dictionaries.

Comment: Yes, my French dictionary is identical : DICTIONARY="French "
  FILE="%B\Dict\French\fr.dic"
  ENABLED=1
  MODE_FILTER="FR"
  LOAD_ON_START=1
  SAVE_ON_EXIT=1
  ADD_NEW_WORDS=0
  USE_FOR_COMPLETION=1
  ALLOW_COMPOUNDED_WORDS=1           

I suppose this would be more a problem if Winedt didn't find my dictionary. It clearly does find it now, since the dictionary works just fine - the problem is just removing it from documents where I don't want it to be active. Curiously, I get the following error message when opening Winedt :  WARNING "C:\Program Files\.....fr.dic not found"

Comment: That's what `MODE_FILTER="*;EN;UK;US|FR"`in Dictionaries.ini for the various english dictionaries is for: the `|FR` means it is not used for the FR submode.

Comment: @Bernard, I'm afraid I still don't understand what I should modify in the dictionaries.ini file. Is it the entry of the French dictionary that should be changed, and if so, how? I've tried to add the |FR part to the English dictionary. However, even though the document has Submode : TeX:FR (I've also tried to clal it just FR), the English dictionary is still active. And conversely the French dictionary is also active for all documents, including new ones that I open. Both dictionaries remain active, regardless of all attempts so far...

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand why it doesn't work,. I must say I'm  under Windows 7, so if you have a more recent version of Windows, maybe there are subtle differences. Maybe you should ask the author, Aleksander Simonic. Usually, he answers very quickly.

Comment: @Bernard, thank you for all your efforts. I will follow your advice.

Comment: Do you have any news for us? Is the issue solved? How?